# Getting test file resource with maven

Tags: maven, unit-testing, io

I'm trying to get a json file resource in order to use it to build a java object. When I try to run my code in the Intellij I don't have any problem, but when I run with `mvn test` I get the follow error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project cadastur-backend-business: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create test class 'guiaVOTemplate.json'
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultScanResult.loadClass(DefaultScanResult.java:135)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultScanResult.applyFilter(DefaultScanResult.java:95)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.scanClassPath(JUnit4Provider.java:222)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:107)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: guiaVOTemplate.json
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultScanResult.loadClass(DefaultScanResult.java:131)
[ERROR] ... 6 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :cadastur-backend-business
```

The project has the follow structure:

[Project Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZncN.png)

And above has the code where I'm trying to read the file and convert the json to java object.

```
package br.gov.mtur.cadastur.builder;

import br.gov.mtur.cadastur.vo.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GuiaVOBuilder {

    private GuiaVO guia;

    public GuiaVOBuilder() {
        this.guia = new GuiaVO();
    }

    public GuiaVOBuilder comId(Integer id) {
        guia.setId(id);
        return this;
    }

    public GuiaVOBuilder comPessoaFisica(PessoaFisicaVO pessoaFisica) {
        guia.setPessoaFisica(pessoaFisica);
        return this;
    }

    ... //Builder methods

    public GuiaVO build(){
        return guia;
    }

    public GuiaVO buildGuiaCompleto() throws IOException {
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(GuiaVOBuilder.class.getResource("/guiaVOTemplate.json"), GuiaVO.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try copying the `guiaVOTemplate.json` file to `src\main\resources` and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you @RITZXAVI, now it's working for me, but do you know why I can't put the json file in `src\test\resources`?

Comment: sure. How did it work by the way ?

Comment: I followed your suggestion.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I miss understood your comment...

Comment: Let me add this an an answer. Mind accepting it  and upvoting ?

Comment: I put the guiaVOTemplate.json in src\main\resources as you said. But I'm still  in doubt because I can't put the json file in src\test\resources, since it's a resource test file.

Comment: Actually GuiaVOBuilder is in `src\test\java\...`, because this I was trying to put my resource file in `src\test\resources`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the `guiaVOTemplate.json` file to `src\main\resources` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I find my mistake, in the main `pom.xml`, the maven-surefire-plugin was including all files, so because this I was getting `Unable to create test class 'guiaVOTemplate.json'`. So I could resolve this putting files with extension `.json` in the exclude list, as bellow. And my `guiaVOTemplate.json` remains in `src/test/resources`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.json</exclude>
        </excludes>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```